# Can we install agent for azure deployment group in our remote VM without internet access(offline)?

Tags: .net, azure-devops, continuous-integration, continuous-delivery, azure-deployment

I tried installing agent in my remote server by running the registration script(from deployment groups) in powershell. But I'm getting an error. And I don't have internet access in that server.So Is it possible or we have any other way to install agent(even manually) without having internet access in our remote server(VM)?

Edit- this is the error I'm getting:

```
Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send." At line:1 char:1303 + ...nalString, $True);}; $WebClient.DownloadFile($Uri, $agentZip);Add-Type ... +~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+CategoryInfo : Not specified:(:)[], 
ParentContainsErrorRecordException 
+FullyQualifiedErrorId: WebException
```

Comment: why dont start by sharing a) what script you are running and b) what error you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring to the script provided by Azure DevOps within the deployment group configuration, yes, **you will need an internet connection** to use that script. Its installation steps reach out and download the agent files.

What you can do to circumvent this is:

1. install and configure the agent exactly as you would on the server on another machine.
2. Then, disable and uninstall the windows service on that machine.
3. Copy the files installed in the **agent** or **azagent** folder (or a custom folder, depending on your configuration) to the desired location on your build agent.
4. Manually set up the windows service to run the agent on your build server.

Please note, that even using this method, you will likely run into issues if the machine does not have an internet connection at all. When the agent starts, it's going to attempt to communicate with Azure DevOps to verify its connection. If it fails, the service will fail to start.

Comment: Thank you so much @Max Morrow, I have a doubt- Is Just providing "https://dev.azure.com/"  domain(internet) access enough for downloading and installing the agent in server??

Comment: No problem! Offhand, I'm not certain which URLs that script is going to access. I'd recommend running fiddler and checking out what it's trying to access when it runs.